# Can't fix int and float error in economic simulator

Tags: python, simulator, economics

I'm making an economic simulator type thing in python and when trying to calculate total cost when buying something i keep getting either an int error or a float error please help.

can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

```
import time
money = 1
moneyfo = "{:.2f}".format(money)
woodinv = 0
woodsalea = 1
woodprice = (woodsalea / 2)
woodpricefo = "{:.2f}".format(woodprice)
amntw = 0
float(amntw)
buywcost = 0
print ("Prducts are wood food and stone")
print ("Prices are wood(" + woodpricefo + ")")
bos = input("""Buy Or Sell
""")
if bos == ("Buy"):
  btyp = input("""Wood, Food, Or Stone?
""")
  if btyp == ("Wood"):
    amntw = input("0-100")
    buywcost = float(amntw) * woodprice
    buywcostfo = "{:.2f}".format(buywcost)
    print ("That will be" + float(buywcostfo) + "you have" + money + "would you like to buy")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just like the error says--you can only concatenate strings to other strings--i.e. when combining strings using the `+` operator, you must actually combine *strings*.

Here is my edited version of the code. I think you avoid the error in question, though I would also recommend making it more readable by adding comments and using more descriptive variable names.

```js
import time
money = 1
moneyfo = "{:.2f}".format(money)
woodinv = 0
woodsalea = 1
woodprice = (woodsalea / 2)
woodpricefo = "{:.2f}".format(woodprice)
amntw = 0
float(amntw)
buywcost = 0
print ("Prducts are wood food and stone")
print ("Prices are wood(" + woodpricefo + ")")
bos = input("""Buy Or Sell""")

if bos == ("Buy"):
  btyp = input("""Wood, Food, Or Stone?""")
elif btyp == ("Wood"):
  amntw = input("0-100")
  buywcost = float(amntw) * woodprice
  buywcostfo = "{:.2f}".format(buywcost)
  print ("That will be" + str(float(buywcostfo)) + "you have" + str(money) + "would you like to buy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are here:

```
print ("That will be" + float(buywcostfo) + "you have" + money + "would you like to buy")
```

You need to convert numbers to strings before adding them to other strings:

```
print ("That will be" + str(float(buywcostfo)) + "you have" + str(money) + "would you like to buy")
```

Also, this isn't doing what you probably intend:

```
float(amntw)
```

You have to save the result of the conversion to a float - it doesn't change the number in-place:

```
amntw = float(amntw)
```

However, as you do this:

```
amntw = 0
float(amntw)
```

Assuming your intent was to make `amntw` the float equivalent of `0` you can simply set it directly as a float value:

```
amntw = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your print statement you are casting the type to a float and so you are trying to concatenate a string and a float in 2 different places, python does not allow this.

**Change this line**:

`print ("That will be" + float(buywcostfo) + "you have" + money + "would you like to buy")`

**Option 1**:

`print ("That will be" + buywcostfo + "you have" + str(money) + "would you like to buy")`

**Option 2**, Python also has a feature called f strings which allow you to put variables directly inside the string:

`print(f"That will be {buywcostfo} you have {money} would you like to buy")`

Answer (score 0):

only you have to change the last line as follows

```
print ("That will be " + str(float(buywcostfo)) + " you have " + str(money) + " would you like to buy")
```

you can choose print formattings as given [here](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/185759/printing-string-and-integer-or-float-in-the-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're initializing variables before they're being used. That's not necessary in python.

```
amntw = 0     # You don't need any of this
float(amntw)      # float() isn't doing anything here without assignment
buywcost = 0  # It's just making your code messy
```

And don't do `str(float(buywcostfo))` as others are suggesting. That would be redundant. Since `buywcostfo` is already a string, you would be casting a string to a float and back to a string again.

```
buywcost = float(amntw) * woodprice # buywcost is now a float
buywcostfo = "{:.2f}".format(buywcost) # buywcostfo is a string
print("That will be" + float(buywcostfo) ...) # now it's a float again - can't add to string
```

You should read up on [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). They can make your life easier and really clean up your code a lot.

```
# This way unless the variables buywcostfo and moneyfo are needed elsewhere, 
# they can be removed completely.
print(f"That will be {buywcost:.2f} you have {money:.2f} would you like to buy")
```